# PrestaShop 1.7 local development using docker

Tags: docker, prestashop-1.7

I realize this might be a basic question. I just have not found a clear tutorial guide yet.

I have been learning about docker and I now understand the basics. I also have the mysql and prestashop containers up and running in Ubuntu 16 and have successfully ran the initial PrestaShop website installation on my local computer.

Question: My goal being PrestaShop development using docker, how do I access the files locally other than through the container from the terminal so that I can modify them using my editor?

Comment: Found the solution to be the use of volumes in docker.

Comment: Can you post the solution? Thanks

Comment: Michael Käfer the following was helpful.  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers

Comment: can you share you docker-compose or Dockerfiles for running the prestashop against mysql container?

Comment: I have been searching for the same thing.

Here are some tutorials I found so far:
1. https://www.docker.com/101-tutorial/
2. https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/environments/docker/

Basically, you need to learn how to use a docker compose file, then define your environment. Seems like it's better to have all the files in one volume rather than having the modules and themes separately.

Answer (score 4):

This is my docker-compose.yml that I use to develop Prestashop themes locally. Not perfect as I need to install prestashop manually the first time.

N.B. [theme-name] needs to be the same as the name in your theme config.yml or it won't work

```
version: "3"

services:
  my-prestashop:
    image: "prestashop/prestashop:1.7"
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER=my-mysql
      - PS_DEV_MODE=1
    networks:
      - my-network
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/themes/[theme-name]

  my-mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

More info on how to setup the prestashop container here: https://hub.docker.com/r/prestashop/prestashop/

Comment: Do you use webpack?